# Cocoapod: Why I pass the 'pod lib lint' validation, but failed when I do 'pod spec validation'

Tags: cocoapods

It said

-> MarsTool (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
    - WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 1 warning.

but actually there are some files in the source_files in my local path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of this failure is not pushing a tag to the repo specified in the `s.source` attribute of the podspec that tags the desired source to validate.